# When does comment get auto-generated when flagging question as potential duplicate?

Tags: support, comments, flags, duplicate-questions

When I've flagged questions as potential duplicates in the past, a comment was auto-generated to that effect.  When I just did the same thing, no such comment was generated ([How to structure Util classes in RoR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604955/how-to-structure-util-classes-in-ror)).

The only circumstance I know that was different was that I'd just "answered" the question and had my answer turned into a comment as being "trivial".  I then deleted the comment before flagging the question, on the assumption that a flag-related comment would be auto-generated.

Anyone know what's up? Was the system behavior recently changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system checks all the previous comments to see if a link to that question already exists somewhere in the comments. If it does, it won't create *another* link to that question since it already exists.

However, based on experience, this check is fairly loose and inaccurate. It will catch links in both the forms of `/q/#` and `/questions/#/slug`. From what I can tell, it simply scan the links for the ID number extracted out of the URL you're closing as a duplicate, and applies it to a basic pattern such as `stackoverflow.com/*/#/*`, so it basically catches any question URL which would use that ID number.

Note that this does **not** catch short URLs for answers (in the form of `/a/#`) even though the answer may be *on* that question, since the question's ID number does not actually appear anywhere in that URL.

I'm not 100% on whether deleted comments are supposed to be included in that check, but my guess would be that they are. Since your answer-converted-to-comment contained a matching link to the question, a new link would not be generated.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my recent experience,  when I cast a close vote as duplicate,  an auto remark was generated with a link to the duplicate.

The only time it wasn't generated was when I created a manual comment before casting the close vote.  I assume it's only generated if you don't create a manual comment.

I guess your answer that was converted to a comment and then was deleted still counts as a manual comnent that prevents the generation of the auto comment.

Comment: Makes sense. Think it's worth submitting as a defect (i.e. the behavior in the case of a deleted comment)?